# Overloading operators for class with cast operator and single-argument constructor

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, typecast-operator

I have such code

```cpp
class Number
{
    int m_value;

public :
    Number(const int value) : 
        m_value(value)
    {
    }

    operator const int() const
    {
        return m_value;
    }

    int GetValue() const
    {
        return m_value;
    }
};

bool operator==(const Number& left, const Number& right)
{
    return left.GetValue() == right.GetValue();
}

class Integer
{
    int m_value;

public :
    Integer(const int value) : 
        m_value(value)
    {
    }

    operator const int() const
    {
        return m_value;
    }

    bool operator==(const Integer& right) const
    {
        return m_value == right.m_value;
    }

    bool operator==(const int right) const
    {
        return m_value == right;
    }

    int GetValue() const
    {
        return m_value;
    }
};

bool operator==(const int left, const Integer& right)
{
    return left == right.GetValue();
}

int main()
{
    Number n1 = 1;
    Number n2 = 1;
    int x3 = 1;

    n1 == n2;
    n1 == x3; // error C2666: 'operator ==' : 3 overloads have similar conversions
    x3 == n1; // error C2666: 'operator ==' : 2 overloads have similar conversions

    Integer i4 = 1;
    Integer i5 = 1;

    i4 == i5;
    i4 == x3;
    x3 == i4;

    return 0;
}
```

For class `Number` I have two errors as shown in the code above. For class `Integer` everything is OK. The problem is, I want to keep in resulting class single-parameter constructor, cast operator and equality operations (`MyClass == int`, `int == MyClass`, `MyClass == MyClass`), but I want to implement only one version of `operator==` as in class `Number`. I don't see any way to do this. Is that even possible or I must have all three implementations as in class `Integer`? I know why I get these errors I just don't like the solution I have.

Comment: Please change name `n3` to `x` to avoid confusion, Likewise `n4` and `n5` to `i1` and `i2`.

Comment: Try `explicit` constructor definition for `Number`

Comment: A silly solution: If you get rid of `bool operator==(const Number left, const Number right)`, then the three types of comparisons you want (`Number == int`, `int == Number` and `Number == Number`) will be implicitly converted to ints and it will compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In class `Number` you define a conversion operator to `int` and your constructor allows converting an `int` to a `Number`. Therefore, when comparing a `Number n` and an `int x` for equality, ambiguity arises: should the compiler invoke the built-in `operator ==` for `int`s and convert `n` to an `int`, or should it rather pick your operator and convert `x` to a `Number`? Both conversions are equally good, and it can't choose one.

So yes you have to define three versions, or add a template operator which can perfectly match the type of all arguments and forward to your operator explicitly, like this one (but you most likely want to guard it with some `enable_if` to limit its applicability only to the appropriate `T` and `U`):

```
template<typename T, typename U> // beware: this will match anything. to be constrained
bool operator == (T n, U const& u)
{
    return (Number(n) == Number(u));
}
```

Comment: That is the primary reason why you should be careful with providing implicit conversions.

Comment: I've never worked with enable_if before, so I'll try to figure it out. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can define only one `operator==` as member function:

```
bool operator==(const int& right) const
{
    std::cout << "custom\n";
    return this->GetValue() == right;
}
```

Then,

- `n1==n2`: `n2` will be converted to `int` and custom operator will be used.
- `n1 == n3`: custom operator will be used
- `n3==n1`: built-in operator will be used

Note, that you want your `operator==` be `const` to be able to compare constant `Number`s

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you can make `operator int` explicit.

Another approach would be to use SFINAE to have a template `==` that works for one or more `Number` args, but that is using a bazooka to kill an ant.